# Reference to array not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I am confused from the result of the following code: I can't get my expected result:

```
$arrX = array('a'=>array('val'=>10),'b'=>array('val'=>20), 'c'=>array('val'=>30));
foreach( $arrX as &$DataRow )
{
    $DataRow['val'] = $DataRow['val'] + 20;
}
foreach( $arrX as $DataRow )
{
    echo '<br />val: '.$DataRow['val'].'<br/>';
}
```

Output:
30, 40, 40

Expected: 
30, 40, 50

But again if i make small chage it works fine,

```
$arrX = array('a'=>array('val'=>10),'b'=>array('val'=>20), 'c'=>array('val'=>30));
foreach( $arrX as &$DataRow )
{
    $DataRow['val'] = $DataRow['val'] + 20;
}
foreach( $arrX as &$DataRow )
{
    echo '<br />val: '.$DataRow['val'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour after loop by reference - Is this a PHP bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question (almost exactly) is addressed on the php foreach manual page :)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#92116

Comment: for the casual/curious reader (and because links do break over time), what's the solution say, basically?

Answer (score 3):

You need to **unset** the `$DataRow` after the loop in which you are making use of it as a reference:

```
$arrX=array('a'=>array('val'=>10),'b'=>array('val'=>20), 'c'=>array('val'=>30));
foreach( $arrX as &$DataRow ) {
    $DataRow['val'] = $DataRow['val'] + 20;
}

// at this point $DataRow is the reference to the last element of the array.
// ensure that following writes to $DataRow will not modify the last array ele.
unset($DataRow);

foreach( $arrX as $DataRow ) {
    echo '<br />val: '.$DataRow['val'].'<br/>';
}
```

You can make use of a different variable and avoid the unsetting..*although I would not recommend it as $DataRow is still a reference to the last array element and any overwrite of it later on will cause problems.*

```
$arrX=array('a'=>array('val'=>10),'b'=>array('val'=>20), 'c'=>array('val'=>30));
foreach( $arrX as &$DataRow ) {
    $DataRow['val'] = $DataRow['val'] + 20;
}

foreach( $arrX as $foo) { // using a different variable.
    echo '<br />val: '.$foo['val'].'<br/>';
}
```