# PHP Foreach Pass by Reference: Last Element Duplicating? (Bug?)

Tags: php, arrays, loops, reference

I just had some very strange behavior with a simple php script I was writing. I reduced it to the minimum necessary to recreate the bug:

```
<?php

$arr = array("foo",
             "bar",
             "baz");

foreach ($arr as &$item) { /* do nothing by reference */ }
print_r($arr);

foreach ($arr as $item) { /* do nothing by value */ }
print_r($arr); // $arr has changed....why?

?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => baz
)
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => bar
)
```

Is this a bug or some really strange behavior that is supposed to happen?

Comment: Do it by value again, see if changes the 3rd time...?

Comment: @Shackrock, it doesn't appear to change any more with repeating loops by value.

Comment: Interestingly if you change the second loop to use something other than $item then it works as expected.

Comment: always unset the item at the end of the loop body: `foreach($x AS &$y){ ... unset($y); }` -- it's actually on php.net (don't know where) because it's a much made mistake.

Comment: The PHP manual recommends calling `unset($item);` after the first foreach loop to avoid this problem. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: It is not a bug, just horrible language design!

Answer (score 175, accepted):

After the first foreach loop, `$item` is still a reference to some value which is also being used by `$arr[2]`. So each foreach call in the second loop, which does not call by reference, replaces that value, and thus `$arr[2]`, with the new value.

So loop 1, the value and `$arr[2]` become `$arr[0]`, which is 'foo'.
Loop 2, the value and `$arr[2]` become `$arr[1]`, which is 'bar'.
Loop 3, the value and `$arr[2]` become `$arr[2]`, which is 'bar' (because of loop 2).

The value 'baz' is actually lost at the first call of the second foreach loop.

### Debugging the Output

For each iteration of the loop, we'll echo the value of `$item` as well as recursively print the array `$arr`.

When the first loop is run through, we see this output:

```
foo
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => baz )

bar
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => baz )

baz
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => baz )
```

At the end of the loop, `$item` is still pointing to the same place as `$arr[2]`.

When the second loop is run through, we see this output:

```
foo
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => foo )

bar
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => bar )

bar
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => bar )
```

You'll notice how each time array put a new value into `$item`, it also updated `$arr[3]` with that same value, since they are both still pointing to the same location. When the loop gets to the third value of the array, it will contain the value `bar` because it was just set by the previous iteration of that loop.

### Is it a bug?

No. This is the behavior of a referenced item, and not a bug. It would be similar to running something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { $item = $arr[$i]; }
```

A foreach loop isn't special in nature in which it can ignore referenced items. It's simply setting that variable to the new value each time like you would outside of a loop.

Comment: Sweet, that makes sense. Is this defined behavior or should I file a bug report?

Comment: I have a slight pedantic correction. `$item` is not a reference to `$arr[2]`, the value contained by `$arr[2]` is a reference to the value referred to by `$item`. To illustrate the difference, you could also unset `$arr[2]`, and `$item` would be unaffected, and writing to `$item` wouldn't affect it.

Comment: This behavior is complex to understand and may lead to problems. I keep this as one of my favorites to show my students why they should avoid (as long as they can) things "by reference".

Comment: Why does `$item` not go out of scope when the foreach loop is exited? This seems like a closure problem?

Comment: @jocull: IN PHP, foreach, for, while, etc do not create their own scope.

Comment: @regality: This is by design.

Comment: @jocull, PHP doesn't have (block) local variables. One of the reason it annoys me.

Comment: is there a way to 'reset the var'? so I can use the $item again?

Comment: @RafaelMoni Easy. Just add `unset($item);` after the first foreach loop, as recommended in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 33):

`$item` is a reference to `$arr[2]` and is being overwritten by the second foreach loop as animuson pointed out.

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) { /* do nothing by reference */ }
print_r($arr);

unset($item); // This will fix the issue.

foreach ($arr as $item) { /* do nothing by value */ }
print_r($arr); // $arr has changed....why?
```

Answer (score 4):

It's very surprising behavior, but widely declared as not a bug. PHP (at time of writing) doesn't have block level variables. If you expect for `$item` to go out of scope when the loop is exited you will find that it does not.

Here is a simplified example:

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');
foreach($arr as $item){
    echo "$item\n";
}    
echo $item;
```

Which outputs:

```
one
two
three
three
```

As other people already said, you're overwriting the referenced variable in `$arr[2]` with your second loop, but it's only happening because `$item` never went out of scope.

Comment: 1) Not a bug. It's already called out in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and dismissed in a number of bug reports as intended. 2) Doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: It caught me out not because of the scope issue, I expected $item to remain around after the initial foreach, but I didn't realize that foreach UPDATES the variable instead of REPLACING it. e.g the same as running unset($item) before the second loop. Note that the unset does not clear the value (and thus the last element in the array) it simply removes the variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP does not create a new scope for loops or `{}` blocks in general. This is how the language works

Answer (score 0):

The correct behaviour of PHP sould be a NOTICE error in my oppinion.
If a referenced variable created in a foreach loop is used outside the loop it should cause a notice.
Very easy to fall for this behaviour, very difficult to spot it when it happened.
And no developer is going to read the foreach documentation page, it's not a help.

You should `unset()` the reference after your loop to avoid this sort of issue.
unset() on a reference will just remove the reference without harming the original data.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you use by ref directive (&). last value will be replace by the second loop and it corrupt your array.
the simplest solution is to use different name for second loop:

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) { ... }

foreach ($arr as $anotherItem) { ... }
```