# Pointers in PHP issue

Tags: php, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behavior Of foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)
>   [Strange behaviour after loop by reference - Is this a PHP bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

Can anybody explain me why this code:

```
<pre>
<?php

$a = array('page', 'email', 'comment');
$b = array('page' => 'realpage', 'email' => 'reaLmail', 'comment' => 'c');
$c = array();

foreach ($a as &$item) {
        if (isset($b[$item])) {
               $item =  $b[$item];
        }
}


foreach ($a as $item) {
        $c[] = $item;
}

print_r($c);
```

Outputs

```
 Array
(
    [0] => realpage
    [1] => reaLmail
    [2] => reaLmail
)
```

???
Why BEFORE second loop a is (by var_dump)

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "realpage"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "reaLmail"
  [2]=>
  &string(1) "c"
}
```

But in first iteration, a is

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "realpage"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "reaLmail"
  [2]=>
  &string(8) "realpage"
}
```

and on second and third [1] and [2] indexes are the same "reaLmail", and [2] is pointer?
Thank you!

Comment: BTW, there are no pointers in PHP (in userland at least), `&` is the reference operator (they're similar in C++, but not the same thing).

Comment: if you place `var_dump($a);` after first `foreach` you'll see that last item of array is actually a poiner. So last ` $c[] = $item;` doesn't work and `$item` remains the same from previous iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `foreach (... as &..)`, then `unset` is required as describe in the php manual:

```
foreach ($a as &$item) {
        if (isset($b[$item])) {
               $item =  $b[$item];
        }
}
unset($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `&` in the first loop, which makes it a reference. Remove it, and your example should work fine.

```
foreach ($a as &$item)
```