# Adding items to multi dimensional array in a for loop

Tags: php

This is my array and I want to add some elements to make it like 2nd array

1.)

```
array(7) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(9) "airG Chat"
    ["product_id"] => int(2469)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
  }

  [1] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(9) "PingChat!"
    ["product_id"] => int(7620)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(25) "MobiEXPLORE Zagreb County"
    ["product_id"] => int(8455)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
  }
}
```

After adding items, it should be like this, I tried using for each function but did not work.
2.)

```
array(7) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(9) "airG Chat"
    ["product_id"] => int(2469)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
    ["description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
    ["brief_description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
  }

  [1] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(9) "PingChat!"
    ["product_id"] => int(7620)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
    ["description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
    ["brief_description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    ["name"] => string(25) "MobiEXPLORE Zagreb County"
    ["product_id"] => int(8455)
    ["price"] => string(4) "0.00"
    ["description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
    ["brief_description"] => string(23) "this is the custom test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `foreach` with reference (`&`):

```
foreach($data as &$datum) {
    $datum["description"] = "this is the custom test";
    $datum["brief_description"] = "this is the custom test";
}
```

If you'd prefer not to use `&` ([to avoid this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220457/135448)), you can do

```
foreach($data as $i => $datum) {
    $data[$i]["description"] = "this is the custom test";
    $data[$i]["brief_description"] = "this is the custom test";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use foreach and want to change the original array, you need to add `&`.

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) {
  $item["description"] = "this is the custom test";
  $item["brief_description"] = "this is the custom test";
}
```