# foreach and reference

Tags: php, reference, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behavior Of foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach)
>   [Strange behaviour after loop by reference - Is this a PHP bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug)

I do have a problem with Foreach, I can't understand the second foreach.

why the third part of $foo array has 'two' in its value!

In as much as we know, if we remove the '&'(in first foreach) the problem will solve, but why?

```
<?php

$foo = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($foo as &$bar)
{
// no-op
}

var_dump($foo);

foreach ($foo as $bar)
{
 // no-op
}

var_dump($foo);
?>
###############################################
```

produces:

```
 array(3) {
   [0]=>string(3) "one"
   [1]=>string(3) "two"
   [2]=>&string(5) "three"
  }
   array(3) {
  [0]=>string(3) "one"
  [1]=>string(3) "two"
  [2]=>&string(3) "two"
  }
```

Comment: That second foreach is basically: `foreach ($foo as $foo[2])`. So each iteration, you are updating the last element of $foo with the current element. And since the last element is lost, you ultimately end up with the second-to-last in the last position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

So in your case:

```
<?php

$foo = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($foo as &$bar)
{
    // no-op
}

var_dump($foo);

unset($bar);

foreach ($foo as $bar)
{
 // no-op
}

var_dump($foo);
?>
```

Comment: I'd have called this a bug, didn't expect it to be documented. While testing I also discovered that `unset` in-between the loops does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I know we can use unset.
But I don't understand why does the '&' change the value of array?!

Comment: See [Matthew's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656915/foreach-and-reference/11656964#comment15447102_11656915).

Comment: so This is a bug.thanks.

Comment: @wandad No it isn't a bug. It is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the first foreach you're using a reference with '&' symbol, so the values are actually modified. I don't know what it inside of first foreach but you're overwriting old values, that's why in your second foreach values are not the same as in the beginning.

**Edit** There's a neat answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/strange-behaviour-after-loop-by-reference-is-this-a-php-bug), or just use unset as recommended

Comment: Have you tried running the code in the question? It produces that output, and there's no (obvious) over-writing going on, just the two foreach loops.