# Why does this PHP code output 1,2,2?

Tags: php

Friend posted this PHP snippet.

```
<?
$a=array(1,2,3);
foreach ($a as &$item){}
foreach ($a as $item){}
print_r($a);
```

The output is `1,2,2` - why?

Comment: can you post the php snippet?

Comment: Sorry, on mobile and couldn't figure out how to format it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany As you can see on the edit, it wasn't always there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/php-foreach-pass-by-reference-last-element-duplicating-bug

Comment: The code was hidden because of the  `<` at the begin of the line (without 4 spaces to indicate a bloc of code)

Comment: Because PHP is not a programming language...