# foreach variable reference / php bug or not

Tags: php, foreach

```
$values= array();
$values[1]='test1';
$values[2]='test2';
$values[3]='test3';
$values[4]='test4';
echo '<u>Before:</u><br/>';
foreach ($values as $lang => $value)
    echo $lang.' '.$value.'<br/>';
foreach ($values as $lang => &$value)
{

}
echo '<u>After reference:</u><br/>';
foreach ($values as $lang => $value)
    echo $lang.' '.$value.'<br/>';
```

The result :

**Before:**

- 1 test1
- 2 test2
- 3 test3
- 4 test4

**After**:

- 1 test1
- 2 test2
- 3 test3
- **4 test3**

Why index 4 equal test3?

Comment: or of [PHP Foreach Pass by Reference: Last Element Duplicating? (Bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220399/php-foreach-pass-by-reference-last-element-duplicating-bug#8220457)